# Override Google's new reCaptcha to make it responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, recaptcha

I am struggling to find a way to override google's new recaptcha styling. I believe the new version loads its styling from within the api JS file.

Would anyone know how to override this to make it responsive within bootstrap?

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=onload"></script>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="key"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

just make the iframe responsive like this

```
.g-recaptcha{
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  padding-top: 0px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  }
  .g-recaptcha iframe{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
this will make it res
```

Comment: Good and working idea but the captcha has now some overflow problems in some languages with longer text like german.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below mentioned code

```
.g-recaptcha {transform: scale(0.85); transform-origin: left top;}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would add just one more things to Boukraa Mohamed idea:

```
.g-recaptcha > iframe
```

This way it will work even if the iframe down-inside of multiple div tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your question makes not clear which properties you want to override.

The Google's code loads an iframe in the div with class `g-recaptcha`. The iframe has its own styles sheets. You can manipulate the style sheets in an iframe with javascript or jQuery, see: [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe).

Before using jQuery to manipulate the style sheets you should make sure that the iframe had loaded. <strike>See: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#explicit_render</strike> it seems that the api does not provide a function to trigger this onload event.